# How to detect a pseudo-console in Python in order to activate coloring?

Tags: python, jenkins, travis-ci, tty, ansi-escape

The usual rule for apps that support console coloring is to activate it when the current console is a TTY.

This method breaks on continuous integration servers (like Jenkins, Travis,...) because they do not open a TTY for their pseudo-console.

I am wondering if it is possible to distinguish between these two cases:

- `mycommand` run under Jenkins - we want to enable coloring
- `mycommand >> output.log` -- we don't want to end up with ANSI escapes in the log file.

My old ANSI detection code:

```
import sys
import os

if (hasattr(sys.stderr, "isatty") and sys.stderr.isatty()) or \
    ('TERM' in os.environ.keys() and os.environ['TERM'] in ['linux']) or \
    ('PYCHARM_HOSTED' in os.environ.keys()):
    coloring = True
```

Can I improve this in order to address this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are already using the Environment Variable `PYCHARM_HOSTED`, I suggest you use something similar for you CI environment.  You mentioned Jenkins and Travis specifically.  Both of these systems set environment variables that can be used.  Some possibilities are...

**Jenkins Environment Variables:**

```
JENKINS_URL  Set to the URL of the Jenkins master that's running the build.
BUILD_URL    The URL where the results of this build can be found.
BUILD_TAG    String of jenkins-${JOB_NAME}-${BUILD_NUMBER}.
```

([Source](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-JenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables))

**Travis Environment Variables:**

```
CI=true
TRAVIS=true
CONTINUOUS_INTEGRATION=true
```

([Source](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Default-Environment-Variables))